# list.add is crashing when I try to add user defined object

Tags: android, listview, arraylist

I'm trying to create Android app that takes user input to create a player list and keep     the order but I've been trying to do this with an ArrayList that takes int position and String name but when I try to `playList.add(player)` my app crashes.
I have been trying to add to an ArrayList `playerList = new ArrayList<Player>();` I have tried `List<Player> = new ArrayList<Player>` as with no luck.
 The data is being passed back and shows up in Toast but now ListView item.  What am I missing?
This is my MainActivity:

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.SharedPreferences;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MotionEvent;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.TableRow;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {
        private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 10;
        private SharedPreferences savedPlayerPositions;
        private PlayerActivity playerActivity;
        public List<Player> playerList = new ArrayList<Player>();
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            // set up preferences
            savedPlayerPositions = getSharedPreferences("playerPositions",
                    MODE_PRIVATE);

            ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
            List<Player> playerList = new ArrayList<Player>();

            CustomListViewAdapter adapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(this,
                    playerList);
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);

            Button addPlayerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
            addPlayerButton.setOnClickListener(addPlayerButtonListener);

            playerActivity = new PlayerActivity();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        public OnClickListener addPlayerButtonListener = new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // onClick go to player input screen and PlayerActivity
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClass(MainActivity.this, PlayerActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        };
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == 10) {

        String position = data.getStringExtra("battingPosition");
        String name = data.getStringExtra("playerName");
        int positionInt = Integer.valueOf(position);
        Player player = new Player(positionInt, name);
        **playerList.add(player);**
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), position + " " + name,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Here is my customListViewAdapter:

```
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class CustomListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter
    {  
        LayoutInflater inflater;
        List<Player> playerList;

        public CustomListViewAdapter(Activity context, List<Player> playerList) {  
            super();

            this.playerList = playerList;
            this.inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);}

        @Override  
        public int getCount() {  
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
            return playerList.size();  }  

        @Override  
        public Object getItem(int position) {  
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
            return null;  }  

        @Override  
        public long getItemId(int position) {  
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
            return 0;  }

        @Override  
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {  
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub  

            Player player = playerList.get(position);
            View vi=convertView;

            if(convertView==null)
                vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_player_view, null);

            //assign components from new_player_view
            TextView playerInfo = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.txtV_player_input_name_title);
            Button editButton = (Button) vi.findViewById(R.id.btn_Edit_Title);
            editButton.setOnClickListener(MainActivity.editPlayerButtonListener);

            playerInfo.setText(player.batPosition + " " + player.name);

            return vi;  
        }
    }
```

xml mainActivity:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/txtV_battingOrder_Title"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/btn_AddButton_title" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="442dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.89" >
        </ListView>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Row that is added to listView:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtV_player_input_name_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
            android:maxLength="2"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:width="180dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_Edit_Title"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/btn_edit_player_width"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/txtV_player_input_position_title"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txtV_player_input_position_title"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:text="@string/bnt_Edit_title" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: where is your logcat output? in which line it is crashing? Dont just copy your whole project here, Just keep it as short as it can.

you declared PlayerList twice in your code that might be a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
public List<Player> playerList = new ArrayList<Player>();
```

to

```
public ArrayList<Player> playerList = new ArrayList<Player>();
```

And also change inside your onCreate:

```
List<Player> playerList = new ArrayList<Player>();
```

to

```
playerList = new ArrayList<Player>();
```

but you don't have to redeclare twice since onCreate is only ever called once in an Activity's lifetime.

You will also have to call:

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

each time the playlist array is changed.

Comment: That fixed it: playerList = new ArrayList<Player>.  I can't believe I wasted so much time on this problem. Thanks for the head up on the notifyDataSetChanged. I not new to Java but very inexperienced.

Comment: No problems, yeah lists can be a hand full.

Answer (score 0):

you have already declared `playerList` as a class variable so you no need to declare again in `onCreate` just use the variable which you have declared before.

and use your `Toast.makeText` method in `onActivityResult` like this

```
Toast.makeText(this, position + " " + name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```